# How to iterate over columns of 1D an 2D arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that wants to test a predicate on columns of a numpy array, let's say that they all sum up to 10. The function will either take a 1D or a 2D array, with the 1D array being treated as a single column.

For the 2D case I can do something like:
`python
for col in two_dim_array.T:
    assert sum(col) == 10`

And I know for the 1D case I can simply do:
`python
assert sum(one_dim_array) == 10`

But is there a way to have a single code path that is agnostic of the type of the array, i.e. I don't have to switch on `len(my_array.shape)` and use either of the code snippets above, something like:
`python
for col in one_or_two_dim_array.cols():
    assert sum(col) == 10`

Where for the 1D case we would only pass through the loop once.

Answer (score 2):

The following yields a 1-D array of column sums in both cases:

```
column_totals = one_or_two_dim_array.sum(axis=0).flatten()
```

You can then loop over the values in `column_totals` if you want, or assert all the comparisons in one go:

```
assert np.all(column_totals == 10)
```

In fact the whole thing can be abbreviated to one line:

```
assert np.all(one_or_two_dim_array.sum(axis=0) == 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that?

```
import numpy as np

def test(arr):
    if np.ndim(arr) > 1:
        arr = arr.T

    for col in arr:
        assert np.sum(col) == 10

arr1 = np.array([1,2,3])
arr2 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(test(arr1))
print
print(test(arr2))
```